# nodejs и mysql подключение

Tags: mysql, node.js

Подскажите, если пишешь
 `conn.query("SELECT * FROM goods", (error, data) => {`

вне строки `app.get("/", (req, res) => {`

то все ок, т.е. выводит в консоль, если ошибка, он ее видит, а если этот код после app.get (как в примере), то вообще никаких ошибок и код не работает, как будто он его не видит:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "shop",
});
conn.connect();

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("node express work on 3000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  conn.query("SELECT * FROM goods", function (error, data) {
    if (error) return console.error("Ошибка: " + error.message);
    console.log(data);
  });
  res.render("index.html");
});
```

Comment: перенесите вызов `res.render("index.html");` в callback, последней строкой